# How to update the Total Entries on Gravity Forms using gform_product_info

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

The hook below override the total on the gravity forms and show the users the discounted total amount based on the qty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){

if(formId != 11)
return total;
if(jQuery("#input_11_6").val() > 2){
     total *= .6;
    return total;
} else if (jQuery("#input_11_6").val() > 1) {
    total *= .7;
    return total;
}
else if (jQuery("#input_11_6").val() != 1) {
    return total;
}
return total;

} );
```

now my problem is when checking the user entries in the backend it shows the original total amount. any advice would be a great help.

Comment: Just including a link to the gform_product_info filter for others looking to help out: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_product_info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to update the entries in the backend, you need to add a filter on your theme function.php

```
 add_filter( 'gform_product_info', function( $product_info, $form, $entry ) {
// add your code here.

}, 10, 3 );
```

example code here. https://pastebin.com/xgYYXyTh

Comment: damn been scratching my head, this is what I'm looking for, many thanks for your code.